# How can we efficiently store a block tridiagonal matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am solving a linear system in which the matrix is block tridiagonal. Let B be the 99 by 99 tridiagonal matrix with 4 on the main diagonal and -1 on the two sub-diagonals, and let I be the 99 by 99 identity matrix. I want to store the block tridiagonal matrix A of size 99^2 by 99^2, which the main diagonal is B, and the sub diagonals are -I. What is the most efficient way to do this? I came up with one way:

```
t1=ones(99,1);
t2=ones(98,1);
B=4*diag(t1)-diag(t2,-1)-diag(t2,1);
I=diag(t1);
Bp=repmat({B}, 99, 1);
M = blkdiag(Bp{:});
t3=ones(9702,1);
I=zeros(9801)-diag(t3,-99)-diag(t3,99);
A=M+I;
```

I am not sure whether this is the most efficient way to do this. Any other possible approaches to this?

Comment: Store it as a sparse matrix https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html (if you have a new enough version)

Comment: @Richard "Introduced before R2006a" - Not much danger of not having a new enough version, I think.

Comment: @Richard Sparse matrices were introduced in MATLAB circa version 7.0 (around 2004).  Versions of MATLAB this old cannot run on most operating systems currently so it is safe to say that any current MATLAB user will have a version that is older than 7.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this one using [spdiags](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html):

```
B_size = 99;
A_size = B_size^2;

v = ones(A_size,1);
D = [v*-1, v*-1, v*4, v*-1, v*-1];
A = spdiags(D, [-B_size, -1, 0, 1, B_size], A_size, A_size);
```

Here's the sample output for `B_size = 4`:

```
D =

  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
  -1  -1   4  -1  -1
```

The columns each represent a diagonal in our sparse matrix. The second parameter `[-B_size -1 0 1 B_size]` in the call to `spdiags` tells it which diagonal to put each column on (negative numbers are below the main diagonal, positive numbers above). Unneeded values from the column vectors (the bottom values for negative diagonals, top values for positive diagonals) are ignored.

`A` is a sparse matrix, so I'll show `full(A)` so you can see what it actually looks like:

```
>> full(A)
ans =

   4  -1   0   0  -1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  -1   4  -1   0   0  -1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0  -1   4  -1   0   0  -1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0  -1   4  -1   0   0  -1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  -1   0   0  -1   4  -1   0   0  -1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0  -1   0   0  -1   4  -1   0   0  -1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0  -1   0   0  -1   4  -1   0   0  -1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0  -1   0   0  -1   4  -1   0   0  -1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0  -1   0   0  -1   4  -1   0   0  -1   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0  -1   0   0  -1   4  -1   0   0  -1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   0   0  -1   4  -1   0   0  -1   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   0   0  -1   4  -1   0   0  -1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   0   0  -1   4  -1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   0   0  -1   4  -1   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   0   0  -1   4  -1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   0   0  -1   4
```

Comment: Really like this method. Thanks a lot!